# Google Analytics Universal Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

We are using the new Google Analytics Universal code, but our event tracking code does not seam to be working. Any ideas on what is wrong? Thank you.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'mywebsite.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>


<a href="http://www.outbound.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'label');">Click Here</a>
```

No events show up in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the Google Analytics tracking code is asynchronous. The user leaves the page before Google Analytics Javascript code can ping the Analytics server.

To fix this, you need to either open the outbound link in a new window, or set a [hit callback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback), which will ensure the Analytics "hit" happens before the navigation.

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'label', { 'hitCallback': function() { document.location = 'http://outbound.com'; }}); return false;" href="http://outbound.com">Click Here</a>
```

The example code would allow you to navigate the site with and without javascript, and search engines will see the link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any chance you can provide some sample code to show the proper way to add the hit callback, and then redirect to the outbound URL.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the time you took to answer the question!

Comment: How do you mean open the link in a new window? The onclick with `ga` seems to catch the click and prevent the default `<a target="_blank"...` from functioning, and using `window.open(url)` in the `hitCallback` triggers a popup warning and is blocked

Comment: @BenSwinburne If the original page is staying open, you shouldn't need to have Google Analytics handle the navigation in the hitcallback. I've never had it prevent the `__blank` from functioning. Maybe worth posting a new question with you exact circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'label', {'hitCallback': function() {document.location = 'http://outbound.com'}});">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Word of warning with this, it will not function if Javascript is disabled in the clients browser. Also it could effect search engines crawlers because they won't see the link because it's quite embedded in the `hitCallback` function, or if they do, they won't understand how it works completely.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Wasn't considering folks with js disabled and search engines. I'll leave my answer "as-is" rather than deleting it, so people have an example of what-not-to-do :) Thanks Again @StevenV