# External Jquery Loads - first OnClick function works all the time second OnClick works intermittent

Tags: jquery

I load the following from an external js that tracks pdf and zip clicks in Google Analytics. The pdfOnClick function works all the time, but the zipOnClick works  intermittent.

```
(function () {
function loadScript(url, success) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        done = false;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
            done = true;
            success();
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            head.removeChild(script);
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',

function () {
    $("a[href$='pdf']").each(function (index) {
        pdfLabel = $(this).attr('href');
        pdfOnClick = "ga('send','event','PDF','downloaded','" + pdfLabel + "');";
        $(this).attr("onClick", pdfOnClick);
    });    

    $("a[href$='zip']").each(function (index) {
        zipLabel = $(this).attr('href');
        zipOnClick = "ga('send','event','ZIP','downloaded','" + zipLabel + "');";
        $(this).attr("onClick", zipOnClick);
    });
});
})();
```

I created a jsfiddle to see if jshint showed any issues, but it comes back clean.

My question is do you see a reason why the pdfOnClick function works all the time, but zipOnClick does not?

http://jsfiddle.net/cbww3zr3/2/

@osowskit You mention handling users without javascript enabled. Is it best to scrap the jquery and just assign it to the action something like:

```
<a onclick="ga('send','event','zip','downloaded','label',{'hitCallback': function() {document.location = 'http://example.com/test.zip';}}); return false;" href="http://example.com/test.zip" target=_blank>Click Here</a>
```

Comment: To properly work the GA hitCallback must block page navigation until the GA event callback returns.  On sessions without JS, this will break navigation.  The point was to handle this case with JS disabled - if you feel it is necessary.

Comment: @osowskit - I think I need to find out the reality behind if I really even need it before wasting more of your time. Not sure how to determine how many users have js disabled. Looked around last night in ga but didn't find anything on that. Will go with the jquery I already posted for now since adding target=_blank fixed the initial issue. I will post another question if I need to expand this. Thank you again for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404011/1375964).

The difference in behavior you are seeing is that the first link opens a new page/tab while the second navigates to the zip directly.  For the second case, the GA event is getting cancelled before GA receives the event.

You can open a new link/window or use the GA hitCallback (remember to handle users without Javascript enabled).

When I debug GA events I always watch the network traffic in the Developer Tools of my browser.  In Chrome you can preserve the log between pages which will clearly show the GA event getting (canceled).

Comment: thank you for the response.  I will look into using Chrome the developer tool and GA hitCallback.

Comment: I updated the question. Looking for clarification if you have time.

Comment: your best bet is to leave this question alone and open a new one. I'll keep an eye out for it but make sure it has the google-analytics tag to help it get picked up